# fread the same file, but return different result

Tags: c, windows, fread

Today, I read a blog named by "a bug of fread?", I didn't find any reason for it, so I paste it here waiting for any genius.

First, the purpose of the program is to read a file(readme.txt) and print the content, and I test it with Visual Studio 2010.

The content of the readme is :

```
1234;
abcd;
ABCD;
```

The hex value of readme is :

> 31 32 33 34 3b 0d 0a 61 62 63 64 3b 0d 0a 41 42 43 44 3b

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int rcnt = 0;

    char rbuf[BUF_SIZE];

    fp = fopen("readme.txt", "r");
    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        printf("fopen error.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("--------------------------\n");
    memset(rbuf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    rcnt = fread(rbuf, 1, BUF_SIZE, fp);
    printf("read cnt = %d\n", rcnt);
    printf("%s\n", rbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

Such a simple code, and the expected result is :

```
--------------------------
read cnt = 17
1234;
abcd;
ABCD;
```

Total 17 count include 15 characters and 2 '\n'.
But I got the below result:

```
--------------------------
read cnt = 17
1234;
abcd;
ABCD;D;
```

PS: If call fopen function with "rb", or if define the macro BUF_SIZE smaller, I got the correct result.

Comment: It would be interesting with a link to the original blog post, too.

Comment: I am not sure that there is anything that `fread` is doing wrong here. It doesn't overflow the buffer you gave it, the count it returned is correct and the content of the buffer that it claims is valid (the first 17 bytes) is the same as that part of the file. :-)

Comment: memset (&rbuf... would be a bit more readable

Comment: I can't reproduce this in GCC 4.6 or Clang 3.0.

Comment: Did you write the file as text or binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's wrong to use `fread()`, a *binary* reading API, with a text file. The default mode (if you just say `"r"`) is text.

Note that `FILE *` I/O in text mode typically does line-termination translation, so that you can pretend that lines end with `\n` when they might in fact physically end with `\r\n` (as yours do).

This conversion might introduce confusion somewhere; which is why switching to binary mode makes it work again as no such translation happens in binary mode.

Comment: Maybe I got the reason. When windows read a file as a text mode, the `\r\n` would be replcaed with `\n`, however, ftell function would count the `\r` character.  I think windows internally read the file in binary mode to the buffer, and then move the data if a `\r` found, so we will got the unexpected result. However, when I try to read a file twice in code, first time I got the expected result, while the second time I got the unexpected.

Comment: The point of the above comment is that you should read the file twice in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`fread()` doesn't return a NUL terminated string, but `printf("%s")` ask for a NUL terminated string.

You have to add a '\0' at the end of the **read** buffer: `rbuf[rcnt] = '\0'`.
And remember to read one byte less than the buffer size to leave room for the NUL byte.

Comment: He's using `memset(rbuf, 0, 1024)` while `rcnt` is `17`, so `rbuf` should be null-terminated.

Comment: @netcoder No, he's giving a buffer of 1024 bytes, so `fread()` is free to use up to 1024 bytes and then return a length of 0. AFAIK POSIX doesn't say anything about not using the whole buffer.

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't say anything about using it either. Besides, what would it put in there if there's no data, magic? (that actually would make sense considering the result) Anyway, it's not POSIX either (it's MSVS after all), and I can't actually reproduce this problem in POSIX.

Comment: @netcoder don't try to be smarter than POSIX: if it's not specified, **any** behavor is allowed and valid. But nevertheless, it should be checked by POSIX expert.

Comment: It's not POSIX, it's Windows.